# how do we handle white spaces in Website name

Tags: powershell, command

My requirement is to add a web application to Default website and enable the directory browsing for the same.
I am using following command line to create the application.

```
 C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv> .\appcmd.exe add app /site.name:"mytest" /Path=/test4 /PhysicalPath:"c:\test
```

This is working fine.But if i try to put website name as following:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv> .\appcmd.exe add app /site.name:"Default Web Site" /Path=/test4 /PhysicalPath:"c:\test
```

It gives errors.Please help :)

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this question has been tagged with Powershell, here's a powershell solution using the [WebAdministration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx) module:

```
Import-Module webadministration

# Create the Web Application
New-WebApplication -Name testApp -Site 'Default Web Site' -PhysicalPath c:\test -ApplicationPool DefaultAppPool

# Set directory browsing enabled
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/directoryBrowse -name enabled -PSPath 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' -Value $true
```

Comment: :This command is for creation of web application and i have used it but i am not getting a way to set directory browsing on web application using powershell,becos of that i moved to command line and there facing problem with white spaces.If there is way we can set directory browsing in powershell on web application,then that solves my issue.

Comment: Updated with an example of how to enable directory browsing

Comment: :thank u so much.It helped me :)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm not entirely sure why people thought this wasn't a real question, it seemed valid to me.